# jQuery .data() Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question has been asked before, but I can't find any answers that have been given since May 2010. If one or more of these answers are still relavent, I'd be happy to delete this question.

Does jQuery have a selector that will allow me to filter by values added by `.data()`?

**Example: (see comments)**

```
//Set IsValid data attribute on all elements that have fired the blur event
$(".txtPayment").blur(function (e) {
    if (IsCurrency($(this).val()))
        $(this).data("IsValid", true);
    else
        $(this).data("IsValid", false);

    SumPayment();
});

//Sum all payments

// I'd like to be able to select all inputs with:
// class == "txtPayment" value != "" && IsValid == true
$('.txtPayment[value!=""]').each(function ()
{
    var sum = 0;

    if ($(this).data("IsValid"))
    {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
        $(this).removeClass("textError");
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass("textError");
        $("#spanSumPayment").addClass("textError");
    }
});
```

Is this possible **without plugins?**

Comment: The answers are great, but as an alternative you can [make your own jQuery selectors](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/) for fun and profit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does jQuery have a selector that will allow me to filter by values added by `.data()`?

Almost. It has a function to do this.

```
$(".txtPayment").blur(function () {
    $(this).data("IsValid", IsCurrency($(this).val()) );
    SumPayment();
});

var validOnes = $('.txtPayment[value!=""]').filter(function() {
  return !!$(this).data("IsValid"));  // (!! turns anything into a Boolean)
});
```

Comment: Nicely done, thanks. Thanks also for the optimization of my original code - concise and readable.

Comment: @JamesHill FYI You could also do things like `$('.txtPayment[value!=""]').toggleClass("textError", function() { return !!!$(this).data("IsValid"); });`

Comment: @Tomalak why would you negate it three times instead of just once?

Comment: @Kevin: Because... why, you are right. That makes no sense. :) I'll correct it (damn, if only I could edit my older comments). — `!$(this).data("IsValid");` is enough, of course.

Comment: @tomalak I just thought maybe you knew something I didn't, :p

Comment: @KevinB PS: Yay, another ColdFusion developer! ;) They are pretty scarce on this site...

Answer (score 1):

No. Why don't you want to use a plugin? You could always do something like this, using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('.txtPayment[value!=""]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("IsValid");
}).each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: I have nothing against plugins. I put that in my OP because I had already found a plugin to do it and I wanted to see if there was a "native" way to do it before I used a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can select by attributes that existed when the page loaded, such as `data-id="5"`, however, not by data set with `.data()`. You can however use the `.filter()` method for both.

```
$('.txtPayment[value!=""]').filter(function(){
  return $(this).data("isValid");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If it's not listed [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), it can't be used as a selector.

If you'd like to store all the elements with a certain piece of data in a variable, you can use `filter()`, for example:

```
var dataElements = $('.txtPayment[value!=""]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("IsValid");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively manually set the data attributes of an element like this in jQuery:

```
$(element).attr('data-test', true);
```

This will allow you to either access data with the data() function, like this:

```
$(element).data('test'); ==> true
```

While allowing you to select the element in jQuery/CSS like this:

- `element[data-test]` - will only check for the `data-test` attribute's presence
- `element[data-test="true"]` - will also apply a condition to the attribute selection